# How to refresh data in a Ionic page?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm working on Ionic 4 and I'm trying to understand the basic concepts of it. So I have encountered a problem with the application I'm working currently.

One of its function is to display the information of the user, everything shows correctly except two variables. 
This is my part of `.ts` of the page

```
ngOnInit() {
this.slug = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
this.loadData(); }

loadData() {
if (this.dataService.loaded) {
  this.userList = this.dataService.getUserlist(this.slug);
} else {
  this.dataService.load().then(() => {
    this.userList = this.dataService.getUserlist(this.slug);
  });
}}
```

...

```
displayActvLvl(): string {

let temp: string;
let val: number;
val = this.userList.actLvlVal;
if (val === 1.2) {
  temp = 'No Active';
} else if (val === 1.375) {
  temp = 'Lightly Act';
} else if (val === 1.55) {
  temp = 'Moderate Active';
} else if (val === 1.75) {
  temp = 'Very Active';
} else if (val === 1.9) {
  temp = 'Athlete';
}
return temp;}

displayGender(): string {
if (this.userList.gender) {
  return 'Female';
} else {
  return 'Male';
} }
```

and this is the two items that are not showing the information

```
    <ion-row>
  <ion-col size="6">
    <ion-item text-center>
      <ion-label position="stacked">{{displayGender()}}</ion-label>
      <ion-note>Gender</ion-note>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-col>

  <ion-col size="6">
    <ion-item text-center>
      <ion-label position="stacked">{{displayActvLvl()}}</ion-label>
      <ion-note>Activity Level</ion-note>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

I know the issue but i can not figure out a solution. For what i understand, when the data is loaded from the Data Service, and then the page is initalize, that's when the two functions run but the two items don't refresh themselves. Any help?

this is the load function from the data Service

```
load(): Promise<boolean> {
return Promise.resolve(true);
```

}
Edit: 
GetUserList function from the Data Service

```
getUserlist(id): UserInfo { return this.userList.find(userinfo => userinfo.id === id);}
```

Comment: Can you please share getUserlist() function's code from your DataService?

Comment: @ZearaeZ I put it on the main post

Answer (score 0):

The async pipe is used with Observables or Promises. 
Since your functions are synchronous, removing the pipes from the template html should probably fix the issue?

Comment: I’m sorry, I forgot to delete that, I was trying to make the functions async using promises and pipes but I couldn’t so I went back one state but I forgot to delete it from the .html file. Thanks for the answer tho

Comment: Sure. Do feel free to upvotes/accept the answer if it solved your problem :)